# "GWT DateBox" Z-Index css property not working on DateBox widget in GWT

Tags: java, css, gwt

I have a pop-up panel. I have made the background blurred using following code-
In .java file-
this.setGlassStyleName("popup-glass2");

In .css file

```html
   .popup-glass2 {
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: 0.6;
    filter: literal("alpha(opacity=30)");
    z-index: 2;
}
```

I have used the following code for Pop-up panel-
In .java file-
this.setStyleName("popup-header");
In .css file

```html
.popup-header{
   background-image: url(../images/popup-border-grey.png);
   font-size              :    100%;
   border              :  5px solid #BDBDBD;
   z-index:10;
}
```

Note:If I don't use z-index property in .popup-header the whole scree becomes black.

I have a widget DateBox on the pop-up panel which is not opening when I use this z-index property for blurring the background.
So, what changes should I do so that the background is also blurred and my DateBox also opens.

Answer (score 0):

on your date-box - remove all styles 
and then set-style as popup-header2 with out z-index - it might work

Comment: what is  popup-header2? add a new style on datebox or something else?

Comment: popup-header2 will be same as -->  popup-header . Do not include the z-index in popup-header2 . It might work.

Comment: It doesnt work. If I remove the z-index from  .popup-header and I have it in .popup-glass2  then all the screen becomes black, gets covered with the glass.